# problem with clone - jquery/php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, clone

I have a div that has inside a piece of php code

I need to replicate the div and the php, how i can do that?

clone method doesn't work obviously with php , only clone the div but without the php code.

```
<div id="wrap" style="margin: 80px;">
        <p>
            <label>Área profissional :</label> <select name="area" class="area">
                <option selected="selected">Seleccione a Área</option>

                <?php
                $sql=mysql_query("select id_formation_area, area from formation_area");
                while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
                    $area=$row['area'];
                    $id_area=$row['id_formation_area'];
                    echo '<option value='.$id_area.'>'.$area.'</option>';
                }
                ?>

            </select> <label>Profissão:</label> <select name="profissao"
                class="profissao">
                <option selected="selected">Seleccione a profissão</option>
            </select> <label>Gráfico:</label> <select name="estatistica"
                class="estatistica">
                <option selected="selected">Seleccione a estatistica</option>
            </select> <span class="remove">Remove</span>
        </p>
        <p>
            <span class="add">Add fields</span>
        </p>
    </div>
```

Comment: can you show us what you need to replicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can't use Client side technology (without ajax support) to clone a server-side code
2. It seems that your mysql query will not return different result if you query it again, which means (point 3)
3. Since your PHP code is generating HTML output, cloning the output will be equivalent to "outputing the whole thing once again"!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to clone the `div#wrap` use:

```
$("#wrap").clone().insertAfter($("#wrap"));
```

Comment: JavaScript is client-side, PHP is server-side. You can't see the PHP code in you browser, so you can NEVER clone the PHP code with JavaScript.

Comment: however, you can duplicate the output of the php!

Comment: i will use ajax and made the query dynamically. I think that is the best choice.

Comment: @user455318. That's the perfect solution!